# Help with a generic LINQ insert method (Norm/MongoDB)

Tags: .net, linq, mongodb, norm

I'm trying to write a generic method to inset an object as an embedded document. The below code works already but I need to make a generic method that can be put in a repository and called from the controller. I'd need to pass in the root ID and the sub-document object that needs to be inserted.

```
class Post
{
    ...
    public IList<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

using (var db = Mongo.Create(session.ConnectionString()))
{
    IMongoCollection<Post> _collection = db.GetCollection<Post>("Post");
    var comment = new Comment();
    comment.InjectFrom(commentViewModel.comment);

    // Use below to add *NEW* embedded document
    _collection.UpdateOne(
        new { _id = commentViewModel.Id },
        new { Comments = M.AddToSet(comment) }
        );
}
```

As an example, this is what I use to retrieve a document, I'm looking for something similar to insert:

```
// Controller
var session = new MongoSession();
var post = session.Single<Post>(c => c.Id == id);

//Repository
public T Single<T>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression) where T : class, new()
{
    T retval = default(T);
    using (var db = Mongo.Create(_connectionString))
    {
        retval = db.GetCollection<T>().AsQueryable()
                    .Where(expression).SingleOrDefault();
    }
    return retval;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Note that calling:

```
_collection.UpdateOne(
            new { _id = commentViewModel.Id },
            new { Comments = M.AddToSet(comment) }
            )
```

does what I need, I just want to be able to make it a generic call (for lack of a better word) to something like this (except a working version):

```
//Controller
var session = new MongoSession();
session.AddSubDocument<>(new Post { Id = commentViewModel.Id }, new { Comments = M.AddToSet(comment) });

// Repository ==> NOT WORKING SAMPLE
public void AddSubDocument<X, U>(X matchDocument, U valueDocument)
{
    using (var db = Mongo.Create(_connectionString))
    {
        db.GetCollection<X>().UpdateOne(matchDocument, valueDocument);
    }
}
```

Hope that makes more sense.

Thank you,
Mike

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
public void Insert<T>( T entity )
{
     using (var db = Mongo.Create(_connectionString))
     {
         var collection = db.GetCollection<T>();
         collection.Save( entity );
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks jfar but that would only work for inserting a full document, not adding an embedded document into an existing one.

Comment: @Mikalee - Thats probably impossible without some reflection magic.  How would you know which field or property to add the nested document into?

Comment: if you look at the example I gave above, it already works, I just don't know how to make it generic. So, by calling _collection.UpdateOne(new { _id = commentViewModel.Id },new { Comments = M.AddToSet(comment) }); the first parameter identifies the root document and the second parameter identifies which (IList Comments) field to add it to. The "M.AddToSet" method does what I need - I'll add some details to my post.

Comment: take a look at the update I just added, I just want to move the method elsewhere and need a way of calling it - not sure how to pass the parameters to it (Id = commentViewModel.Id, M.AddToSet(comment)).